# Any iOS 8 app extensions/extension types that work with iPhone's Message app?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, sms

While reading on app extensions introduced with iOS 8, I noticed that there are extension types that can work with an iPhone user's images, notes etc. But I was wondering if I can make an action or a share extension that would work with iPhone's Message app as the host app. Is there any resources about it?

Edit: I understand that you need to specify a particular data type for app extensions to work on certain data type. Are text conversations a certain data type/object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a misunderstanding of what Share Extensions are.
You embed a Share Extension into your app to offer services of your app to others. Any app that embeds a Share Sheet and provides data of a type your extension offers to handle can (and will) use your extension.

Comment: yes, that's what I thought. I initially wanted to use action extension to perform an action on a text conversation. So, is there a particular data type to signify a text conversation? I know these text conversations are saved in a database, but do they have a data/object type?